# How do I make my Kodi on Xbian/Raspberry use Python 3.9 instead of 3.7?

Tags: python, linux, kodi

Using XBian on Raspberry Pi 3.
I have an addon for Kodi that requires Python v3.8 or later, while the Xbian for Raspberry installation only has 3.7.

I installed Python 3.9 and updated the alternatives, so when I go "python -V" it properly says 3.9.2.
However, Kodi obviously still uses 3.7:

```
Error Contents: cannot import name 'cached_property' from 'functools' (/usr/lib/python3.7/functools.py)
```

In /usr/lib/, I only see the python3.7 folder, and nothing for python3.9.
What am I doing wrong? How do I force python to install the 3.9 libs?
Thanks!

Comment: File locations don't matter, the alternatives command should do the correct thing. Have you inspected the kodi startup scripts to ensure they're not using a hard-coded Python executable? Alternatively, addon developers should be aware that latest Python won't always be available on Kodi systems

Comment: I'm not sure how to check it (if they're using a hard-coded executable), but I'll try to set maximum logging level and re-check the logs. I did raise an issue on Github for the addon developers, but I doubt they are going to do anything about it, and I do need that addon to work soon. Thank you!